# ICF home -- are columns in the photos load bearing?

Tags: concrete, load-bearing

I'm in need of some guidance regarding the two columns in the photos below. I'm trying to determine if they're load bearing. The home is an Insulated Concrete Form ([ICF](https://www.buildwithrise.com/stories/mythbusting-icf-sustainable)) build. I'm planning to remove those doors to the sunroom and potentially remove the columns to open up the space, if they're not load bearing. Any guidance is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i'd open it up and check with the double gang in the middle of one of them there is a chance they aren't.  no way to tell unless you look at plans or open it up.

Comment: No way to tell from pictures... Would need to see the blueprint. Recommend consulting with a structural engineer in your area. Its a lot cheaper to ask before your house collapses.

Comment: What does "open it up and check with the double gang" mean, in words that the sort of person asking this question would understand?

Comment: Be wary of "opening" your living space to a sunroom. If you want just differently framed windows, that's ok. But if you remove the windows, the whole combined space will become a sunroom. With a heatload that will be unbearable in the summer, no AC strong enough to cool it down. And super expensive in the winter, with heating cost sky high. There is a good reason why sunrooms are separated from the rest of the house - they're meant to be something that's neither outside nor inside, partially connected to both, and only partially insulated from both.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a Structural Engineer is required to safely and accurately make these calculations. Lives depend on this being accurate and it shouldn't be entrusted to well meaning random strangers on the internet.

Comment: @nobody - I think the idea is to open up the light switch, and look behind it to see if the structure looks strong enough to be load bearing.

Comment: @FreeMan I don't think there's any harm in asking for a free non-professional opinion on SE with the caveat that a structural engineer will have to make an assessment if they still wish to attempt their idea. OP has been given the advice that they are _likely_ to be load bearing, and therefore they are more informed about the risk of spending a decent chunk of change on an engineer just to be told it can't be done. The advice given here could influence whether they will give up on the idea now before any money has been potentially wasted.

Answer (score 27):

In a concrete wall (which is what an ICF house is built from) those are certainly load-bearing concrete columns. It would have required some very deliberate design to make the header over that space strong enough to carry a massive wall and the roof loads without those columns.

As always, before betting your house on knocking down parts of it, get professional (as in an actual licensed to practice in your area professional engineer) advice, but in this case I'd be stunned if there was a way around that, without planning for it at design time.

Comment: There's a massive wall above those columns? Says who? Without much space for wall bracing (shear walls, I guess, if we're talking about concrete), above these openings would be a wise place to switch materials.

Comment: The wall, being concrete, is, itself, massive.

Comment: Who said the wall above is concrete (I assume that horizontal box contains HVAC serving an upper story)? It's a wood floor system integrated with concrete walls. It's not a costly burden to judiciously use a wood wall system when it fixes a painfully detailed shear wall while allowing all of those openings.

Comment: It's described as an ICF house. All the walls are concrete, ICF being "insulated Concrete Form." It was not described as a "partial ICF house" or "an ICF basement house."

Comment: And somebody asking if those columns are load bearing? Your taxonomy of ICF is familiar and aligned with this somebody's?

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Concrete buildings are not all solid concrete. There are spaces which are empty or have insulation in them. And some can be concrete blocks which, again, are hollow. I don't know about ICF (not familiar with the term) - but you don't have to be fully concrete in order to insulate, plus it's not clear internal rather than external walls are supposed to be highly insulating as well.

Comment: @einpoklum: if you're not familiar with ICF, the critical term and first word in the question, you should familiarize yourself with it before commenting

Comment: I agree they definetly look load bearing, my architectural spider senses tell me that to take the pain to dimension and adding cost of a load bearing beam to hold this length, just to end up hiding it and break the space with fake columns would be rather counter-productive. Even if there is no upper floor and it holds only the roof, it is a big length to hold for housing standards, it would be specially designed, and usually when you do this you show it (apparent beam as a distinctive feature)

Answer (score 5):

Caveat: Amateur rather than professional here.

I am almost certain these are load-bearing. Tell-tale signs for me:

- Columns which are this thick (or rather, with minimum dimension this big) - some of them are always, in my limited experience, load-bearing.
  Otherwise they don't bother to make them both long and thick / wide and deep.  I said "some", because if you have a couple of load bearing columns at least, you could make extra columns of the same dimensions for aesthetic consistency.
- Columns which don't reach the room ceiling, but rather a concrete "beam" below the ceiling line - at least some of them are load bearing. Again, the rest may be a design choice.
- Weaker indication: The room beyond the glass looks somewhat closed-veranda-ish. If that is indeed the case, that means there's not much / not anything above it, and then obviously you need to bear some load at the column line (transferring the load elsewhere would be weird).

... but of course, as [Ecnerwal](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/286078) and others say: Don't rely on people on the web for this stuff, get this determined with certainty by a professional.

Comment: That rectangular box is almost certainly HVAC serving an upper story. The shape is wrong for a beam (for concrete, roughly, strength increases linearly with width or with height, but the height-based increase doesn't require additional rebar). And assuming there's a load bearing wall straight above it, the region above the columns all the way up to the bottom of the next story's windows can theoretically be a monolithic concrete beam. You don't need to intrude into the living space like that with a beam.

Comment: I think we're talking about different boxes. You're taking about the one that sticks out  of the wall with the columns (towards the table), I'm talking about the top part of the wall with the columns. Agree with you that the stick-out space could very well be HVAC or other utility space.

Comment: Ah. I agree that the vertical dividers are probably load bearing, but in a non-load bearing wall the ceiling would come down to frame the door just like that. (The whole portal would be thinner, as you've pointed out.) If not for the sliding doors, then I might agree with you. Even then there's an argument for delineating the transition from one room to another, although I would expect an architect to choose a much more subtle delineation.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the rectangular box above the sliding doors is HVAC duct feeding an upper story, then yes those columns are load bearing. The ceiling joists run perpendicular to that HVAC duct. That's why the duct had to be installed below the floor joist elevation. Technically the ceiling joists could extend beyond the intermediate wall, with the sun room's wall supporting them instead of the intermediate wall, but that's a very, very low probability.

There's also a tiny possibility that instead of load bearing columns, there's a massive beam above the sliding doors that carries the weight of everything above to the corners of the room. Constructing such a beam would entail a great deal of cost, however, where there was probably no incentive for your builder to relay that extra cost on to you. I suppose a subset of these columns could be load bearing, but again, I can't imagine a builder rationalizing the extra cost.

That electrical box on one of the columns provides you a non-invasive means to sneak a peek inside the drywall. I might disassemble it to prod around in there however I could without cutting anything, but this is due diligence, not a "there's hope" situation.